# How to count instances of a SET of characters in SQL Column

Tags: t-sql, wildcard

I need to count instances of a set of characters (aeıioöuü) in each row.

For example:

```
"linebreak" should return 4.
"indent" should return 2
"quote" should return 3
```

I can count one single character with this:

```
SELECT LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col, 'a', ''))
```

I also found a way of counting a set of characters:

```
SELECT LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, 'a', ''), 'e', ''), 'ı', ''))...
```

However this query becomes confusing as it continues to grow. Is there a better method with wildcards or something else?

Comment: i think you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580017/how-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-sql

Comment: It is good to meet CLR UDF. I will use it in subsequent projects. I am using a simpler method for my actual problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

What I actually needed is the rows that has a specific number of a, e, ı, i, o, ö, u or ü; not the number of occurences. The following query returns the rows which have only one vowel character:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM [table]
WHERE col Like '%[aeıioöuü]%'
AND col NOT LIKE '%[aeıioöuü]%[aeıioöuü]%'
```

And this returns the rows which have only two vowel characters:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM [table]
WHERE col Like '%[aeıioöuü]%[aeıioöuü]%'
AND col NOT LIKE '%[aeıioöuü]%[aeıioöuü]%[aeıioöuü]%'
```

And so on...

Comment: When I was looking answer for actual problem, I found myself in methods for counting characters, and then replacing characters, and then CLR UDF, and then Regex...