# How to find a special characters in a string and replace it with a space in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have contact_firstname column which has some special characters like (@,&,-,_, etc) in the data stored in that column. I want to first find all those special characters in each record and replace those characters with a space. I found a query on this website which helps identify the special characters but I am not sure how to find charindex of each special character in the below string and replace it with a space.

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(100)
SET @MyString = '!Char$Fox@'

IF (@MyString LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')
   BEGIN
      PRINT 'Contains "special" characters'

    END
```

Comment: Write a function that loops through each character one at a time, and if it is a special character, replaces it with a space.

Comment: Do you want to display spaces for “special characters” on the screen, output, or `PRINT` statements, or do you want to replace these characters in the database?

Comment: I want to replace special characters in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to loop, as Tab Alleman mentioned:

```
declare @MyString varchar(100) = '!Char$Fox@'
declare @i int = 0
declare @char varchar(1)
declare @len int = LEN(@MyString)
declare @result varchar(100) = ''

while @i < @len
begin
    set @char = SUBSTRING(@MyString, @i, 1)

    if @char like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
    begin
        set @char = ' '
    end

    set @result = @result + @char
    set @i = @i + 1
end

select @result
```

Comment: There is a REPLACE function, but it works one character at a time, and your pattern is really just trying to find any character that isn't an alpha-numeric, so the number of cases would be prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
DECLARE @InvalidChars VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(100)

SET @InvalidChars = '!$@'
SET @MyString = '!Char$Fox@'

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@InvalidChars, 1, 1) AS [String], 1 AS [Start], 1 AS [Counter]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@InvalidChars, [Start] + 1, 1) AS [String], [Start] + 1, [Counter] + 1 
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE [Counter] < LEN(@InvalidChars)
)

SELECT @MyString = REPLACE(@MyString, CTE.[String], ' ') FROM CTE

SELECT @MyString
```

Result:

> Char Fox

This is a combination of solutions found here:

[How to Replace Multiple Characters in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580017/how-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-sql)

[T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

Comment: Thank You all for the help.