# SQL Replace multiple different characters in string

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2016

I need to replace multiple characters in a string. The result can't contain any '&' or any commas.

I currently have:

```
REPLACE(T2.[ShipToCode],'&','and')
```

Which converts `&` to `and`, but how do you put multiple values in one line?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You just need to daisy-chain them:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(T2.[ShipToCode], '&', 'and'), ',', '')
```

Answer (score 42):

One comment mentions "dozens of replace calls"... if removing dozens of single characters, you could also use Translate and a single Replace.

```
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(T2.[ShipToCode], '[];'',$@', '#######'), '#', '')
```

Comment: However, TRANSLATE is only available from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

Comment: Why not TRANSLATE into blanks directly ?

Comment: @Ludovic because SQL spits this error if you try "The second and third arguments of the TRANSLATE built-in function must contain an equal number of characters."

Comment: Is there a performance gain/loss depending how many times you use replace on a single line, or a single replace and translate?

Answer (score 11):

We used a function to do something similar that looped through the string, though this was mostly to remove characters that were not in the "@ValidCharacters" string. That was useful for removing anything that we didn't want - usually non-alphanumeric characters, though I think we also had space, quote, single quote and a handful of others in that string.  It was really used to remove the non-printing characters that tended to sneak in at times so may not be perfect for your case, but may give you some ideas.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_RemoveInvalidCharacters]
 (@str VARCHAR(8000), @ValidCharacters VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
BEGIN
  WHILE PATINDEX('%[^' + @ValidCharacters + ']%',@str) > 0
   SET @str=REPLACE(@str, SUBSTRING(@str ,PATINDEX('%[^' + @ValidCharacters +
']%',@str), 1) ,'')
  RETURN @str
END
```

Comment: Preferring this solution since it doesn't daisy-chain dozens of `REPLACE` calls

Answer (score 11):

If you need fine control, it helps to indent-format the `REPLACE()` nesting for readability.

```
SELECT Title,
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(RTRIM(Title),
                            ' & ',''),
                        '++', ''),
                    '/', '-'),
                '(',''),
            ')',''),
        '.',''),
    ',',''),
' ', '-')
AS Title_SEO
FROM TitleTable
```

Answer (score 10):

If you use SQL Server 2017 or 2019 you can use the [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

```
TRANSLATE(ShipToCode, '|+,-', '____')
```

In this example the pipe, plus, comma, and minus are all replaced by an underscore.
You can change every character with its own one.
So in the next example the plus and minus are replaced by a hash.

```
TRANSLATE(ShipToCode, '|+,-', '_#_#')
```

Just make sure the number of characters is the same in both groups.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this might helps to anyone

If you want to replace multiple words or characters from a string with a blank string (i.e. wanted to remove characters), use `regexp_replace()` instead of multiple `replace()` clauses.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Hello world!123SQL$@#$", "[^\w+ ]", "")
```

The above query will return `Hello world123SQL`

The same process will be applied if you want to remove multiple words from the string.

If you want to remove `Hello` and `World` from the string `Hello World SQL`, then you can use this query.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Hello World SQL", "(Hello|World)", "")
```

This will return  `SQL`

With this process, the query will not look redundant and you didn't have to take care of multiple `replace()` clauses.

**Conclusion**

If you wanted to replace the words with blank string, go with `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

If you want to replace the words with other words, for example replacing `&` with `and` then use `replace()`. If there are multiple words to be replaced, use multiple nested `replace()`.

Comment: Looks like this function is only available for Oracle, and not SQL Server

Comment: This function is available in Google BigQuery and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server to avoid daisy-chain them, you can try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE('?File /03-0>6-99 *Test/*.pdf', '<>:"/\|*?', REPLICATE('~',9)),'~','');
```

Answer (score 0):

For SqlServer 2014 and older, you can write the equivalent of the TRANSLATE function like this :

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.TranslateBefore2016(@chaine NVARCHAR(MAX), @chars NVARCHAR(MAX), @translations @NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @tmp NVARCHAR(MAX) = @chaine
    
    declare @i as integer = 1
    WHILE @i <= len(@accents)
    BEGIN
        SET @TMP = REPLACE(@TMP COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, substring(@chars , @i, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, substring(@translations , @i, 1))

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    RETURN @TMP
END
```

Example of usage to remove accents :

```
select dbo.TranslateBefore2016('ABCDE éeeà', N'ÁÀÂÄÃÅÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÇáàâäãåéèêëíìîïóòôöõúùûüç', N'AAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUCaaaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuuc')
```

Please note :

- The usage of the case sensitive collations
- This function will probably need a test to check that @chars and @translations have