# MySQL query to find a phone number in a table within multiple columns of the table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a debt collection database that has 71 columns in 1 table that could possibly have a phone number in it`(primary phone, work phone, cell phone, custom1, custom2, custom3)` etc..etc... What I'm trying to accomplish is a `C# window` form app that searches for a `phone number` you input into the form and finds a match which will give you the `account number` of the account upon successfully matching the `phone number`.

Not all phone numbers have the exact same format ie. `(444-444-1111, 4444441111, (444)444-1111)` etc....So far I haven't been able to find anything on here as to how I can structure the select statement to find a match. I'm a complete noob at this whole process but from what I've found I could possibly use a CONCAT or  `REGEXP` possibly.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

This is just a mock-up of what I'm thinking.

```sql
select * 
from dbase 
where 
  primaryphone,
  cellphone, 
  workphone, 
  spouseworkphone, 
  spouseemployerphone, 
  employerphone, 
  custom1, 
  custom2, 
  -- all customs fields from 3 to 57
  custom58, 
  custom59, 
  custom60 = '444-444-1111'
```

Comment: Too broad question. We need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), samples of input and expected output. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49455524/edit) your question and add this details

Comment: Just posted a possible query but its erroring out because i cant group all of those fields in the where clause.

Comment: How about normalizing the tables so that all sort of phone numbers are added in a separate table (and normalize the phone numbers to a consistent formant while you are at it).

Comment: Theres only one table that all of the phone numbers go into currently.

Comment: "Normalize" means get rid of  columns that have a numeric indicator (`custom54, custom55, custom56`) - always a bad sign.  DBs are about relationships

Comment: I cant "Normalize" it. I cant manipulate the table at all. I just need help with my query

Comment: The answer provided by @Jcl will solve exact matching. What you are looking for is fuzzy matching, and I have had good success [using the Levenshtein distance algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql), although it was not for phone numbers, so your milage will vary.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select * 
from dbase 
where 
     primaryphone = '444-444-1111'
  OR cellphone = '444-444-1111', 
  OR workphone = '444-444-1111'
  // etc.
```

It's a horrible design, but if it's a one-time thing...

Fuzzy-matching would need another approach and it's quite complicated. For regex you'd have to do a replace but I think mysql doesn't have any built-in regex replacing (again, you could build a custom regex function, but it'd not be simple).

You could do some simple replacements if you know the exact possible separators:

```
select * 
from dbase 
where 
     REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
         REPLACE(primaryphone,'-','')
         ,'(','')
      ,')','') = '4444441111'

  OR REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
         REPLACE(cellphone,'-','')
         ,'(','')
      ,')','') = '4444441111'

//etc.
```

For this, you'd need to pass the searched number without any symbols, and strip (using as much `REPLACE`s as you need) all the known symbols that could be in the records.

Again, horrible horrible design, but the query could be generated by a tool and if you can't change your database...

Comment: Will try that out really quick!

Comment: Yeah, this was for a exact match only... fuzzy matching would take some extra work (I'd say not suitable for a begginer in mysql). I've added a simple replacement query... you'd need to input your phone without any symbols and replace the possible symbols outside the phone number you may find

Comment: This worked! When I try with a different format 444-444-1111 vs 4444441111, I get nothing. Any chance i could use like inside of the where clause?

Comment: Sure, instead of `= '44444111'` you can use `LIKE '%444111%'` or whatever you may want. That's still not fuzzy-matching and would depend on your dataset (you may need more replacements, or whatnot)... but as a one-time thing it could do. What is important is that the data you are searching for contains no separators. You are basically saying "check if the string in this record field without all the separators is equal to this string", so if the record contains "444-111" you are saying: `check if 444111 = <input string>`. If your input string is "444-111" that evaluates to false

Comment: Sorry I deleted the other comment, I had a typo in there. I think I need to have some like's in the where clause since the phone numbers can be formatted differently.

Comment: If you use this solution, it's important that the number you are searching for is stripped of all separators before searching. I explained why in the last comment (basically, it'll be checked against the number in the database without the separators)

Comment: Thank you for you assistance! I have what I need now to complete the query.

Comment: You guys are awesome! This worked for me and is pulling everything I need                                                                                                                  Select * 
from dbase 
where
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(primaryphone, '-','') ,'(','') ,')','') = '4444441111'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jcl's answer, you can also strip out any noise from the fields with [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) in order to get only the numbers, which will increase your matching rate:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbase
WHERE REPLACE(primaryphone, '-', '') = '4444441111'
```

You can chain REPLACES to strip everything:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('(444)444-1111', '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '')
```

If your list of chars to strip gets really long, you can [use a table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580017/how-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-sql)

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding this to my answer! :-)

Comment: Where would the chain REPLACE go inside of the query, could you give me an example, because all of these numbers have ( or ) or / to separate the phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using or statement for all three columns of cell phone you can use CONCAT statement like below!

```
    SELECT *from posts 
    where    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(`primary_phone`,`workphone`,`cellphone`),'-',''),')',''),'(','')
    like '%xxxxxxxx%'
```

Comment: Ill will try this one out

Comment: This did not return any results for this query. I added all of my other fields inside of the ()

Comment: have you searched for number inside like operator?

Comment: I found the error in your statement. You cant have single quotes around the field. But this did work after I edited it.

Comment: SELECT *
from dbase
where
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
CONCAT(primaryphone, workphone, cellphone,),'-',''),')',''),'(','') LIKE '%4444441111%'

Comment: what if primaryphone is `999444444` and workphone is `111122222`? when concatenated they will match the pattern `%4444441111%`.

Comment: yes that will match in that case but that's too much rare. For that case you can use or operator or some other better solution.