# SQL retrieve 4 numbers

Tags: sql-server

How to retrieve rows which contain exactly 4 numbers in Microsoft SQL Server?

This query returns string more than 4 numbers

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
```

Comment: Please Provide us with sample data, and desired results.

Comment: When I execute query above, it show me result like- 'Microsoft Windows 2000 Professional in 24 hours'.(this string contains 6 numbers) and 'Secrets of Windows 2000 Server'(this string contains only 4 numbers). I need that my result table contains only strings with 4 numbers, not 6. How can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is purposely bad at string manipulation, probably to promote Microsoft's client side tooling, like C# or Reporting Server. See for example [this question from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580017/50552).  So the sane solution involves creating a [CLR UDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20140208202630/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

But you can still do it in T-SQL with a lot of trickery. For example, you could create a user-defined function that removes all numbers from a string:

```
create function dbo.StripNumbers(@str nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
as begin
  declare @i int = patindex('%[0-9]%', @str)
  while @i > 0
    begin
    set @str = stuff(@str, @i, 1, '')
    set @i = patindex('%[0-9]%', @str)
    end
  return @str
end
```

Then you can filter for strings that are 4 characters shorter when stripped:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   len(dbo.StripNumbers(txt)) = len(txt) - 4
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7b626/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

You could use wildcards for this:

```
select  *
from    Table
where   Name like '%[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]%'
        and Name not like '%[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]%'
```